# Change size of title in Navigation Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use xamarin forms. To Change title size, I think I need to go through native code

We have a content page, we set title = "Some String" . Can I change the size of title by use custom render? I searched on the internet, there are some solutions change the font, but not size. Anythings helpful, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what did in iOS. This will change the navigation title. I haven't found easy way in android. It seem likes we need to do it with custom view in action bar.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationBar), typeof(CustomNavigationBarRenderer))]
namespace Hello
{
    public class CustomNavigationBarRenderer: NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            this.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Grey
            this.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Black

            this.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes()
            {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-Light", 15),
                ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea about Android?